# Can $L^p(\mathbb{R})$ and $L^p[0,1]$ be isomorphic?

Tags: measure-theory, banach-spaces, lp-spaces, vector-space-isomorphism

Let $1\leq p<\infty$. Are the Banach spaces $L^p(\mathbb{R})$ and $L^p[0,1]$ isomorphic?

The case $p=\infty$ can be treated by seeing that $\mathbb{R}$ and $(0,1)$ are homeomorphic.

Can this be extended to $0<p<1$?

Comment: In this instance going more abstract might help: given reasonable measure spaces $(X_i,\Sigma_i,\mu_i)$, can you say when $L^p(\mu_1)$ is isomorphic to $L^p(\mu_2)$?

Comment: Map $f \in L^{p}[0,1]$ to $F(y)=f(\arctan y)g(y)$ for  a suitable $g$. It turns out that $g(x)=(\cos ^{2}(\arctan x))^{1/p}$ does the job.

Comment: The space $L_p(\mathbb{R}^n)$ (Lebesgue measure implied), $1\leq p<\infty$, is isometrically isomorphic to $L_p[0,1]$. (https://www.math.tamu.edu/~schlump/lecture24and25.pdf)

More generally, if $(X,\mathscr{F})$ countably generated, and $\mu$ is a $\sigma$-finite measure of $(X,\mathscr{F})$, $L_p(X,\mu)$, $1\leq p<\infty$,  is isometrically isomorphic to $L_p[0,1]\oplus\ell_p(I)$ for some countable set $I$.  If $\mu$ has no atoms then one can take $I=\emptyset$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint. Your isomorphism $T : L^p(\mathbb R) \to L^p(0,1)$ will have the form
$T(f)(x) = \varphi(x) f(\psi(x))$ for appropriate functions $\varphi, \psi$.